# Software Updater quits before updating software

Tags: upgrade, 13.10, updates, software-installation, update-manager

I currently have 13.10 Saucy Salamander installed, and I'm following this guide in order to update: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TrustyUpgrades

I got as far as step 6, click the Check button for new updates. There is no Check button, only Settings, Remind Me Later, and Install Now. When I click Install Now, a box comes up saying "To install or remove software, you need to authenticate". I type in my password and hit enter. Another box comes up saying:

```
Software Updater
Requires installation of untrusted packages
This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources.
```

with the options Settings and OK. I click OK and the box just...goes away. Nothing else happens. Nothing is downloaded, the Software Updater doesn't come back, nothing. When I open Software Updater again, the whole process has to be started again.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

**Command Line Method**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

returns a bunch of lines of code but ends with this:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

that also returns a bunch of lines of code but ends with this:

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Finally, `sudo apt-get upgrade` returns the same error as `sudo apt-get update`:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: @EricCarvalho Not a duplicate, it's a completely different method and a completely different error.

Comment: @JoeMorano I guess Eric Carvalho is right about unsupported release, the reason is you're running an outdated release and if you're trying to upgrade to 14.04 some of the packages and ppas can be no longer available in 14.04 they have been stopped in developing or replaced with others that 14.04 requires. The best is to disable all those ppas that you have added in Software & Updates in System Settings you can find that and then run `do-release-upgrade -c -d`

Comment: @JoKeR I found Software & Updates, and I'm in the Other Software tab. How do I find and disable the ppas I added? Should I just uncheck all the boxes?

Comment: well ppas basically come from Launchpad so disable those ppas leave only main and official Ubuntu repos enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As out of my comments the solution that worked for you is to disable ppas that you have added before an upgrade to newer version.

As stated if you're trying to upgrade to 14.04 some of the packages and ppas can be no longer available in 14.04 they have been stopped in developing or replaced with others that 14.04 requires. The best is to disable all those ppas that you have added to Software & Updates in System Settings you can find that for example:

[image]

Unmark ppas corresponding to Launchpad and then run `do-release-upgrade -c -d` there you'll be listed with possible actions to upgrade. And if you need some of those packages from those ppas that you have disabled you can check it in Launchpad for example this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ferramroberto/+archive/ubuntu/sopcast) as you can see its developing has been stopped since 12.10 version of Ubuntu though you can still run it in Ubuntu 14.04 you just have to find another ppa with current package like [this one](https://launchpad.net/~lyc256/+archive/ubuntu/sopcast-player-ppa) or install it manually from `.deb` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following codes in the terminal:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Those all result in errors. I added the resulting errors to my question.

Comment: @Ron I guess he's trying to upgrade to 14.04 but not to update 13.10